# Php Facebook Feed: avoid to display user messages

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Is it possible avoid to display user messages, from my page feed?
Here code:

```
  require 'inc/facebook.php';
  $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                'appId' => $app_id,
                'secret' => $app_secret,
  ));
  $fields = "id,message,picture,link,name,description,type,icon,created_time,from,object_id";
  $fbApiGetPosts = $facebook->api('/' . $page_id . '/feed?limit=' . $limit . '&fields=' . $fields);
  $getFb = array();
  if (isset($fbApiGetPosts["data"]) && !empty($fbApiGetPosts["data"])) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($fbApiGetPosts["data"] as $data)
        {
            echo '<li>' . substr($data['message'], 0, 140) . '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
   }
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/{page_id}/posts` endpoint only shows the page's own posts (if that is what you mean):

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed

> `/{page-id}/posts` shows only the posts that were published by this page.